# How can I exclude some public properties from being serialized into a JsonResult?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, serialization

I have a custom viewmodel which serialized using a JsonResult. The ViewModel has some properties which have to be public, but at the same time these properties should not be visible in the resulting Json output.

I've already tried using the [NonSerialized] attribute, but that did not seem to have any effect.

Is there any simple way to do this? Or would I have to code my own result type (in which case I probably won't bother)?

Comment: Most of the answer is using Attribute or wraper whatever. I just want to simply exclude some of public properties during serializing. I am looking for JSON.NET as suggested by @Charlino but did'nt found the way. This is the case: I have `Error` property which will only set when error occur. client side will check for this first to show message otherwise will display the rest of the Model property. When there is no error, it will render `{...,"Error":null}`!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can put a `[ScriptIgnore]` attribute on the members that shouldn't be serialized. See [ScriptIgnoreAttribute Class in MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.scriptignoreattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) for an example.

Comment: for others out there the full namespace of the attribute is         [System.Web.Script.Serialization.ScriptIgnore]

Comment: Seems like `ScriptIgnore` when using the regular MVC `return Json()` --- then `JsonIgnore` if using `Json.NET`

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx) from James Newton-King. It'll do what you're looking for.

Comment: Perfect! As it turns out, James has also written a matching JsonResult type: http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2008/10/16/asp-net-mvc-and-json-net.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Just create an interface to return instead of a class.

```
public interface IMyViewModel {
   string MyPublicProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Then create a class that inherits the interface

```
public class MyViewModel : IMyViewModel {
   public string MyPublicProperty { get; set; }
   public string MyNotSoPublicProperty { get; set; }
}
```

And return the interface, not the class, in the Controller Action

```
public JsonResult MyJson(){
    IMyViewModel model = new MyViewModel();
    return Json(model);
}
```

And the resulting JSON will be

```
{
    'MyPublicProperty': ''
}
```

One of the challenges in client-side scripting is, that if you're changing your classes, you have no idea whether you're destroying the client-side implementation or not. If you use interface types in your JSON, you understand that if you change the interface, you're doing something that potentially may be killing the client side implementation. And it also saves you from double-checking the client side in vain if you're changing something that is NOT in the inteface (thus not being serialized).

Also, many times, your ViewModels might have large collections or complex types in them that you don't necessarily want to output to the client. These might take a long time to serialize or expose information that simply does not belong into the client code. Using interfaces will make it more transparent to know what is being in the output.

Also, using attributes such as [ScriptIgnore] on a property only applies to a specific scenario (JavaScript Serialization) forcing you to face the exact same problem if you're later serializing to XML for example. This would unnecessarily litter your viewmodels with tons of attributes. How many of them you really want in there? Using intefaces applies anywhere and no viewmodel needs to be littered with extra attributes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's not a bad method, but there is also a more automated way to ensure that your client-side classes are still in sync with the server side: Use Typescript for the client side code and programmatically generate your client-side viewmodels from server side objects during compilation. See http://type.litesolutions.net/ for more details.

Comment: Would this approach work with a List<IMyViewModel> being serialized? I can't make it work...

Answer (score 1):

Extend the [`JavaScriptConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptconverter.aspx) class to not include properties with the `NonSerializedAttribute`. Then you can create a custom `ActionResult` that uses your `JavaScriptConverter` to serialize the object.

This creates a solid and testable class without having to (re)generate wrapper classes or using anonymous objects.

Comment: That's the approach that also came to my mind. It certainly works,  but since this is only about saving a few bytes of each Json request, I was hoping there's something simpler. Good approach, but simply too much work compared to the benefits in my case.

Answer (score 1):

I needed the answer to this for ASP.NET Core 6.x and couldn't find it.

I finally found the answer and it is :

```
[System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonIgnore]
```

Here's an example in a class

```
class Sample{
    // Item will not be serialized
    [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonIgnore]
    String Item{get;set;}
    // Count will be serialized
    int Count{get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly the answer you're looking for, but you can cheat `Json()` using the following code and anonymous classes:

```
MyModel model = ...;
return Json(new MyModel {model.Prop1, model.Prop2});
```

Comment: I know I can use anonymous types instead. But that makes unit testing the result much harder. It means I'd either have to parse the serialized result or use reflection.

Comment: Unit testing JsonResults is tough to begin with.  How were you doing this before?  It doesn't look like you can retrieve the underlying model that drove the JsonResult.

Comment: That's no problem at all. the JsonResult.Data property contains the object that is to be serialized. Since I am using a custom viewmodel instead of an anonymous object type, I can simply grab that object and test it's properties.

Comment: Well, though painful, you could always create a new version of your class and simply copy those properties you want.  I've edited my post with this approach.

Comment: @Adrian: Thanks, I didn't know that Data referred to the serialized object.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a wrapper class that exposes only those properties that you want in the JsonResult. In the example below, Cow has 2 properties - "Leg" and "Moo". Suppose you want to only expose "Leg" as a property. Then

Dim cw as CowWrapper = New CowWrapper(c)

will return a wrapper class that only exposes "Leg". This is also useful for things like DataGridView if you only want to display some subset of the properties.

Public Class Cow

Public ReadOnly Property Leg() as String

```
   get

      return "leg"

   end get
```

end Property

Public ReadOnly Property Moo() as String

```
   get

      return "moo"

   end get
```

end Property

end class

Public Class CowWrapper

```
Private m_cow as Cow = Nothing

Public Sub New(ByVal cow as Cow)

   m_cow = cow

end Sub


    m_cow = cow
```

Public ReadOnly Property Leg() as String

```
   get

      return m_cow.Leg()

   end get
```

end Property

end Class

Comment: This works, but at the price of having to copy quite a few properties, so it's not really what I was looking for.

Comment: At what cost? Programming? It should be simple to write a simple utility to construct these classes given the class file as input, or to write a class that can construct the properties dynamically using introspection. 

Runtime? The cost of an extra reference is neglible.

Comment: I did not realize you mean constructing such types at runtime via reflection. That would of course cover all of my custom viewmodel types without any additional coding. A valid approach but it's too complicated in comparison to using a ready-made tool (namely Json.Net)

Comment: Great! (That there is a ready-made tool). I should have written "it should be possible" not "it should be simple" .. as I don't actually know much about introspection myself.

I've used the wrapper classes (hard coded, not using introspection) when populating a DataGridView with a LINQ to SQL class. Often I don't want to display all fields in the table, so the wrapper takes care of this.